# Пишу телеграм-бота на python для учета прихода и ухода сотрудников

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Для написания решил выбрать библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI. Я хочу, чтобы бот умел фиксировать время прихода человека в виде: #приход 10:00 и фиксировать время ухода #уход 19:00. Для каждого человека отдельно рассчитывалось его время, которое он находился на работе. Желательно, чтобы все данные о времени, которое сотрудники провели на работе выгружалось в отдельную таблицу гугл. Я понимаю, что задача обширна. Я уже делал ботов и знаю как делать простые вещи. Теперь хочу узнать: нужно ли использовать БД для такого бота или достаточно будет гугл таблицы? Кто-нибудь уже делал такого бота? Есть ли смежные решения, куда стоит посмотреть, чтобы не изобретать велосипед заново?

Answer (score 2):

Для данной задачи рекомендую использовать БД с помощью библиотеки `sqlite`

Для того чтобы узнать время в данный момент можно использовать библиотеку `datetime` и метод datetime.datetime.now() для того чтобы узнать время в данный момент

datetime: https://python-scripts.com/datetime-time-python

sqlite: https://proglib.io/p/sqlite-tutorial/

### Реализация

Когда человек приходит если его имени нет в бд то имя записывается и время приход тоже, если его имя уже есть то просто в строку с именем и в ячейку для времени прихода записывается время
а, когда человек уходит время записывается в строку с его именем и в ячейку для времени ухода